# In Qt5.11.1, can `QWebEngineView` call the ActiveX plugin?

Tags: qt, activex, qwebengineview

In `Qt5.11.1`, can `QWebEngineView` call the ActiveX plugin?

If so, how can I call it?

I am working on a browser and want to call the ActiveX plugin with QWebEngineView.
I searched online and found no information.

Comment: What do you mean by "calling" the ActiveX plugin? That phrase is ambiguous. Tell us in plain English what you would like to do. Would you like to display an ActiveX control inside of the webpage contents? Would you like to invoke the ActiveX control that is shown stand-alone, or in some other window? Perhaps provide a hand-drawn sketch of how you want your application to look, and whether the ActiveX plugin is a control (i.e. visible), or not. It is certainly possible, just not as trivial as instantiating an AX control in a legacy IE page.

Answer (score 1):

QWebEngine is essentially Chrome/Webkit.  ActiveX was a technology limited to Internet Explorer. If you need an ActiveX control, you'll likely need to host the Trident control in Windows.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752038(v=vs.85)

Comment: This is technically true, but in practice there are ways around it, since the webpage code can communicate with the Qt application, and the application certainly can overlay ActiveX controls over its window, etc. There's not enough detail in the question to know for sure.